# Let clause as part of join clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join

Why it is possible to use this:

```
from r1 in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
join q1 in Enumerable.Range(1, 20) on r1 equals q1
select r1;
```

but not possible to use this:

```
from r1 in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
let q = Enumerable.Range(1, 20)
join q1 in q on r1 equals q1
select r1;
```

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) on `let clause` lacks some details.

**Update:**
I've just tried to make the expression more clearly readable. In my situation I have some methods chaining that I would like to put to the `let clause`. Otherwise the join clause became too monstrous. As it is not possible to use the `let clause` (as Jon mentioned) I've introduced the outer variable, here:

```
IEnumerable<int> q = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

from r1 in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
join q1 in q on r1 equals q1
select r1;
```

Comment: see the msdn blog link in my answer... they explain it pretty good...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `SelectMany`, a `Join` clause can't depend on the "current" value of the other range variables - so this will work:

```
from r1 in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
let q = Enumerable.Range(1, 20)
from q1 in q where r1 == q1
select r1;
```

... but the join won't.

If you could elaborate on what you're trying to do, we may be able to help more.

Comment: I've updated the question with the solution that works for me as it is not possible to use `let`. But can you explain a bit about the restriction on the `let clause`?

Comment: @Dmitry: It's not so much a restriction on the `let` clause as a restriction on the `join` clause - in the join case, `Enumerable.Range` is called *once* for the whole query, whereas using `let` it would be called *once per element of `r1`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the `join` is evaluated BEFORE the `let`...

Here is blog entry on MSDN explaining this more elaborate - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/01/03/how-linq-to-objects-queries-work.aspx